# Decouple synchronous webservice layer with RabbitMQ, good or bad idea?

Tags: java, web-services, rabbitmq

In my current project we are implementing a webservice layer and we want to decouple this layer using RabbitMQ. This at the end gives me a very thin webservice layer. The challenge with this is that all of the webservice calls are synchronous. The caller of the webservice layer needs to get a response.

I was wondering if it is a good or bad idea to do the decoupling with RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you base your web service on a CQRS pattern where your updates/inserts are handled separately to queries then you can use Rabbit in a de-coupled manner to handle the inserts/updates such that the web service request drops a message containing the information to be inserted/updated on to a queue and then returns. This way, you aren't waiting for the db to commit a transaction.
You would then have a separate service to consume these messages and make the appropriate database insert/update calls.

Your queries would obviously still have to interact directly with your database in order to return information.

As to whether this is a good or bad idea, this is entirely subjective. If your database is pretty simple and inserts/updates take no appreciable time then you may be introducing complexity for little or no net gain. For instance, you could use javascript to make async calls to your web service to handle posts thereby providing a responsive experience to the end user.